# Modify events in calendar to become recurring

Tags: calendar

I am trying to create a Google Script that goes through each event within a time range and modifies the events to a yearly recurring event.  Currently, I mistakenly put in a bunch of birthdays into a calendar, but did not set them as recurring.  Instead of going through each one manually, I wanted to create a script that sets them to a yearly recurrence.  I'm getting stuck on **line 12**.

NOTE: Currently, I simply have my code searching for one specific event called "john bday" but would take out the "if" statement once I get it to modify the existing event correctly.  Please advise and thank you.

```
function myFunction() {

  var fromDate = new Date(2019,0,1,0,0,0); //This is January 1, 2019
  var toDate = new Date(2019,2,31,0,0,0); //This is March 31, 2019
  var calname = "testing calendar";
  var findtitle = "john bday";
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName(calname)[0];
  var events = calendar.getEvents(fromDate,toDate);
  for (var i=0; i<events.length;i++) {
    var ev = events[i];
    if (ev.getTitle()==findtitle) {
      CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addYearlyRule();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this something that I need to create a new series based on the single event and then delete the single event, once the series is created?  Just brainstorming here.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work by copying the event into a new series and then deleting the original event.  Thanks to all of those who took a look at this.

```
function myFunction() {

  var fromDate = new Date(2018,6,1,0,0,0); //This is July 1, 2018
  var toDate = new Date(2019,0,31,0,0,0); //This is January 31, 2019
  var calname = "testing calendar";
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName(calname)[0];
  var events = calendar.getEvents(fromDate,toDate);
  var newRecurrence = CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addYearlyRule();
  for (var i in events){
  var ev = events[i];
     var newEvent = calendar.createEventSeries(events[i].getTitle(), events[i].getStartTime(), events[i].getEndTime(), newRecurrence)
      ev.deleteEvent();
  }
}
```